# Variadic Templates C++. Непонятный код

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Учу вариативные шаблоны. Напал на хабре на статью: [Tuples, unpacking and more](https://habr.com/ru/post/228031/). В статье содержится "набросанная на коленке простейшая реализация" кортежа.

```
 1: template<typename... Args>
 2: struct tuple;
 3:    
 4: template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
 5: struct tuple<Head, Tail...> : tuple<Tail...>
 6: {
 7:     tuple(Head h, Tail... tail)
 8:     : tuple<Tail...>(tail...), head_(h)
 9:     {}
10:
11:     typedef tuple<Tail...> base_type;
12:     base_type& base = static_cast<base_type&>(*this);
13:     Head head_;
14: };
15:
16: template<>
17: struct tuple<>
18: {};

23: tuple<int, double, int> t(12, 2.34, 89);
24: std::cout << t.head_ << " " << t.base.head_ << " " << t.base.base.head_ << std::endl;
```

Как работает наследование и рекурсия, в том числе при инстанцировании шаблонов, я понимаю (мне так казалось до). Но для меня в этом примере загадкой являются строки номер **4 и 5**. Если это частичная специализация, то откуда синтаксис наследования? Если это наследование, то как возможны одинаковые идентификаторы?

Объясните, пожалуйста, что тут происходит

*** UPDATE ***

Благодарность господину [user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670) за помощь!

Оказывается, одновременно можно и специализировать шаблон класса, и при этом наследоваться от специализированного шаблона с тем же идентификатором. Пример от user7860670:

```
template<typename T> 
struct tuple
{ }; 

// частичная специализация + наследование
template<typename T>    
struct tuple<T &> : tuple<T *> 
{ };

// полная специализация + наследование
template< >    
struct tuple<double> : tuple<int> 
{ };
```

А если проделывать это с parameter pack'ом, то благодаря самой его сути всеядности относительно количества принимаемых параметров, можно получить не только код из вопроса, но что-то такое (чего, по всей видимости, нельзя было бы сделать без вариативных шаблонов):

```
template<typename T, typename ... S> 
struct tuple
{   }; 

// без parameter pack'а потребовалось бы указывать тип при наследовании
template<typename ... S> 
struct tuple<int, S ...> : tuple<S ...>   
{   };
```

Comment: Частична специализация никак не ограничивает наследования. Базовый и производный класс - разные.

Comment: @user7860670 Для меня неочевидно, что классы разные, т.к. у них одинаковые идентификаторы. Если заменить в 5 строке "struct _tuple" на "struct _foo", компилятор выдаст ошибку: '_foo' is not a class template. Из чего я делаю вывод, что одинаковые идентификаторы принципиальны. Могли бы Вы подробнее объяснить Ваш ответ? Или направить куда-нибудь почитать)

Comment: Конечно компилятор будет ругаться, ведь частичная специализация может быть объявлена только для шаблона. Если за менять "struct _tuple" на "struct _foo", то и во всех других местах `_tuple` надо переименовывать на `_foo`.

Comment: Да, и стоит заметить, что в данном примере `_tuple` - это не идентификатор класса, а идентификатор шаблона.

Comment: Был бы очень благодарен, если бы Вы привели пример точно такого же наследования с частичной специализацией и одинаковыми идентификаторами, но без использования parameter pack. Просто на примере обычных, невариативных шаблонов. Это поможет мне разобраться

Comment: Да, спасибо, Вы поправили мою лексику. Идентификатор шаблона, разумеется

Comment: Ну например `template<typename T> struct tuple{}; template<typename T> struct tuple<T &> : tuple<T *> {};`

Comment: Компилятор выдает две ошибки в одном и том же месте: `tuple<T &>` : (1) 'tuple' is not a class template, (2) redefinition of 'struct tuple<T>'. GCC-9.2.0 если это важно

Comment: не выдает https://godbolt.org/z/MbKEjPf4d

Comment: Подкрутил. Теперь тоже не выдает. Спасибо Вам большое! Дальше сам надеюсь разобраться. Как тут лайком отблагодарить?